# is there another way for hyperlink

Tags: html

i write these code, but in output, when i click on  a, this will not work.
what should i do so that this works properly.
actually, initially i want to hide filter list and when i type some keywords in input box it will show that possible lists.
till this, it is working properly but when i click on 'a' there is no response.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    #myInput {
      background-image: url('logo.png');
      background-size: 25px;
      background-position: 10px 12px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 98%;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
    }
    
    #myUL {
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    #myUL li a {
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      margin-top: -1px;
      /* Prevent double borders */
      background-color: #f6f6f6;
      padding: 12px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 18px;
      color: black;
      display: block
    }
    
    #myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
      background-color: #eee;
    }
    
    img {
      width: 50px;
      justify-content: center;
      align-item: center;
      position: relative;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translatex(-50%);
    }
    
    span {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="search">
    <img src="logo.png"></img>
    <div id="input">
      <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
    </div>
    <div id="ul">
      <ul id="myUL">
        <li><a href="ghib">Adele</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Agnes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Billy</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bob</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Calvin</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Christina</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Cindy</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var UL = document.getElementById("myUL");
    // hilde the list by default
    UL.style.display = "none";

    var searchBox = document.getElementById("myInput");

    // show the list when the input receive focus
    searchBox.addEventListener("focus", function() {
      // UL.style.display = "block";
    });

    // hide the list when the input receive focus
    searchBox.addEventListener("blur", function() {
      UL.style.display = "none";
    });


    function myFunction() {
      var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
      input = document.getElementById("myInput");
      ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      // if the input is empty hide the list
      if (filter.trim().length < 1) {
        ul.style.display = "none";
        return false;
      } else {
        ul.style.display = "block";
      }

      li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
      for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];

        // This is when you want to find words that contain the search string
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          li[i].style.display = "none";
        }

        // This is when you want to find words that start the search string
        /*if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().startsWith(filter)) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }*/
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

but  href is not working.

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: when i click on a tag, there is no any response.

Comment: Where should each link go? using `href="#"` is essentially telling the computer to stay on the same page. If each `<a>` should go to a separate page, update the `href` tag to point there, e.g. `<a href="/link-to/page" >...` or for external `<a href="https://google.com">...`

Comment: actually i am continuously trying with these. but still this 'a href' are not working. i think the problem may be in java script.

Answer (score 0):

```
// hide the list when the input receive focus
searchBox.addEventListener("blur", function(){
    UL.style.display = "none";
});
```

You are blurring the unordered list whenever you leave the input field, which hides your `<li><a href="#"></a></li>` whenever you click anywhere outside of the input field (hence why the `a href` isn't registering).

Comment: actually, i tried by giving an actual page adress, example: "index.html", but still these are not working.

Comment: Have you tried setting the href to 
`<a href="/">index</a>` or `<a href="/index.html">index</a>`?

Comment: Can you tell me the html in your directory and which page you are trying to get to?

Comment: actually i am continuously trying with these. but still this 'a href' are not working. i think the problem may be in java script.

Comment: i have a file named 'index.html'. And this file named 'search.html'. i make an filter list...in which i create a li.. <li><a href="index.html">Agnes</a></li>. because both file in same folder.

Comment: I've edited my answer, please let me know if that has worked for you! :)

Comment: yes..a href isnt registering.can you solve it please

Comment: Since I can't just give you the answer, I'll give you a hint instead. You'll have to turn off the _blur_ event listener when clicking the _li_ somehow. Learning through failing by doing is the best way to learn!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe "ghib" is a valid href. Either use # for a placeholder or include a URL.

If you were trying to link to another section on your page you'd need to href="#id".

Hope the above helps!